Why can't I read an external Firewire drive because Boot Camp is broken and my Mac mini 2011 only starts up in Windows 8?
I am running macOS 10.13.6 on a Mac Mini 2011 and I decided to get Windows 8 using Boot Camp. The installation went well, but I can't switch back to macOS (I got advice and managed to fix it, but when I loaded macOS I figured out I made a mistake and Windows was broken. So, I installed Windows 8 again and it worked, but once again macOS broke.)
The problem is that I have a 500GB Iomega Firewire drive which was storing just a few photos. On Windows, it just shows 500GB of unpartitioned space.
I really need those photos, how can I read them?

Would you like to recover those few photos? Or what is stopping you from simply reformatting the drive?

yes i really need those photos

I've added an answer with several options, can you take a look at it and provide feedback on whether it solves your issue?

Super sorry for not responding i was away on holiday but i will look now

1: i dont have a older mac 2: probaly my best option 3: im trying to but no one is helping me 4: i dont

the issue now is that the disk is not even showing up at all

No problem :-) So you tried option 2 and the drive isn‘t listed in the Paragon HFS+ for Windows app? You should definitely see the drive, are you sure the driver is installed correctly and the drive has power? If you launch the Disk Management tool, do you see the drive listed ((see https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080 for more information)?

so i did not get hfs+ but instead https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-hfs-windows-driver-download.1368010/#:~:text=These%20are%20the%20Read-Only%20HFS+%20drivers%20that%20comes%20with%20Boot but when i open windows partition manager the disk does not show up

Thank you for your feedback, the Paragon HFS driver has a 10-day free trial (see my updated answer), please uninstall the read-only driver and give the Paragon driver a try.

i installed hfs+ but it is not showing up at all

I think it might be corrupted completely which is really really bad cos i need those photos

the only thing showing up is my macos partion

Yes, I’m afraid the drive is corrupted, sorry about that.

dude i like really really really need those photos like i cant lose them

I'd recommend that you look online for a data recovery company in your area, they may be able to help you and get your pictures back. I'm sorry about this, I hoped you could be able to read your drive using solution 2 below. Although you couldn't recover your pictures, if you feel my answer helped you can still upvote and mark it as accepted.

Thanks so much for trying to help

To access your photos on your Firewire drive, I would recommend one of these methods:

Use another Mac to access the drive. Unless it's a (very) old Mac, you'll need a Firewire 800-to-USB or a Firewire 800-to-USB-C adapter to connect the drive.

Install an HFS driver on your Windows 8 partition.For example, HFS+ for Windows by Paragon Software supports the old macOS file systems HFS Plus and HFSX, and has a 10-day free trial (a license costs 19.95 dollars), then  you could mount and read the drive from Windows 8.

Repair Boot Camp. You mention in your question you were able to fix Boot Camp and access macOS. You could then start up in macOS and read the drive.

If you still have
the original macOS DVD media, install macOS on an external USB disk (or a flash drive) and mount and read the Iomega drive (see https://support.apple.com/111336 for details).
Why do you need the original DVD media?The latest macOS
version your Mac supports (macOS High Sierra, according to Wikipedia)
is only available from the Mac App Store, so you would
need a Mac to download it and create a bootable installer. Other older macOS version supported by your Mac are available for download from https://support.apple.com/102662#browser, but they are formatted as DMG files, and you would again need a Mac to open them and create a bootable installer


